# Problem with running WebGL with Chrome

Tags: 11.10, installation, nvidia, google-chrome, webgl

I just setup ubuntu 11.10 on Dell XPS 15z by following the instruction from here:

[Current status/known issues for DELL XPS 15z?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/74765/current-status-known-issues-for-dell-xps-15z)

Everything seems ok until the point I failed to run openGL on chrome: http://get.webgl.org

This is the step I follow to setup the machine:

1) Add bumblebee ppa

2) install nvida-current from restricted drivers

3) install bumblebee (remember to "sudo usermod -a -G bumblebee YOURUSERNAME" as said by the bumblebee readme)

4) install mesa-utils

5) reboot

6) try intel card with terminal command "glxspheres"

7) try nvidia card with terminal command "optirun glxspheres"

While the step 7 is success, but step 6 was failed with following error message:

Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".

When I run "glxinfo|grep OpenGL", it prompts

"Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0"."

This is my /etc/X11/xorg.conf

```
Section "Device"

    Identifier      "Default Device"

    Option  "NoLogo"        "True"

EndSection
```

I have turned on webgl support for chrome as well.

Fairly new to this, how could I fixed this?

Comment: I fixed that after following instruction with http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work/36936#36936. I got both Intel & Nvidia Graphic Card working. Problem now is chrome still couldn't run webGL, but firefox can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Successfully have it running with both intel and nvidia graphics running by following instruction from here:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work/36936#36936

Did a test on glxinfo | grep OpenGL and optirun | grep OpenGL, both working.

Eventually the webgl issue for chrome is by misconfiguring the chrome://flags, reset it and everything is fine.

Answer (score 7):

As the title does not mention NVidia, (and for those who can run WebGL on Firefox but can't on Chrome) another option is to try enable **Override rendering software list** in

> chrome://flags

Hope it helps

Comment: Exactly what I was after!

Comment: Thank you.  WebGL used to work for me if I used `optirun google-chrome` to launch it.  Then after an update it stopped working and I noticed HTML <video> was jerky.  I tried a few times to fix it and almost contemplated switching to Firefox.  Your answer saved the day.

Comment: Works for me. Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS [GeForce GT 630M]

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar problem. Try starting Chrome with this command `google-chrome --ignore-gpu-blacklist`. Home this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
After installing Bumblebee drivers is used:

```
    optirun /opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --ignore-gpu-blacklist %U
```

It works like a charm!